# SWFTools pdf2swf exactly cropping

Tags: pdf, flash, crop, pdf2swf

I am trying to make a little program to crop PDF pages and export as SWF files which will be displayed on web. I am using SWFTools to crop and convert to SWF by this command line

```
pdf2swf -c x1:y1:x2:y2 mypdf.pdf -o exported.swf
```

But it masks instead of cropping and keeps file size same with full page. I checked swftools wiki pages and documents but found nothing related cropping. is there any way to crop and reduce size?

Comment: I thank everyone who thought about this question. I found the solution 

-G parameter which defined as "Remove as many clip layers from file as possible." worked for me. 

    pdf2swf -G -c x1:y1:x2:y2 mypdf.pdf -o exported.swf

Comment: ^ Thanks for the answer. Would you add it in an answer box, rather than as a comment? `:)`

Comment: @halfer Do it instead of me. I dont have reputation point

Comment: +1, you should be able to now `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution -G parameter which defined as "Remove as many clip layers from file as possible." in pdf2swf help worked for me.

```
pdf2swf -G -c x1:y1:x2:y2 mypdf.pdf -o exported.swf
```

Comment: Do you ever faced any issues of text getting blurred in this process? I am using the same tool, and when the page is larger and swf pages are rendered in smaller area the text readability is lost. Any ways to get sharper text swf files?

Comment: No i have never faced such an issue. Sound like it renders text areas as image. Have you ever tried to convert texts as shapes?
Document says: 
−S, −−shapes
Don’t use SWF Fonts, but store everything as shape.

In other hand, i suggest you to decompile cropped swf and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, i tried with -S parameter. However i am now switching to multiply factor as 2 and generating the swf file in flash 7 version and then converting that to required flash version. It is said that  Flash 7 has better support for fonts, and the difference was visible in very small texts used as some comments in diagrams of PDF files. parameter used are "qq -f -T 7 -t -s bitmap -s storeallcharacters -s multiply=2"